# Maven - Generating JARs GPG signatures

Tags: java, maven, jar, gnupg, sonatype

I'm new with both Maven and uploading things to Sonatype, so the error may be evident but it's hiding well from me. I'm trying to upload an artifact.

To do so, I run the following command

```
mvn clean assembly:single -s settings.xml assembly:single javadoc:jar source:jar gpg:sign -Dgpg.passphrase=myPassphrase install deploy
```

However, this causes Nexus to fail on validating the JAR files because there are no asc signature files included in the upload - which is true, but I don't understand why. Furthermore, there are however signatures of the .xml files and of the .zip, .tar.gz and .tar.bz2 ones. What shall I specify for the ascs to be generated for the jars as well?

Below are shown my settings.xml and pom.xml files:

settings.xml:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>sonatype</id>
      <username>myUsername</username>
      <password>myPassword</password>
    </server>
  </servers>

</settings>
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.github.aaryn101</groupId>
  <artifactId>lol4j</artifactId>
  <version>2.0</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>lol4j</name>
  <description>lol4j is a Java wrapper for the Riot Games LoL beta API.</description>
  <url>https://github.com/aaryn101/lol4j</url>

  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>The MIT License (MIT)</name>
      <url>http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT</url>
      <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
  </licenses>

  <scm>
    <url>https://github.com/aaryn101/lol4j.git</url>
  </scm>

  <distributionManagement>
  <repository>
    <id>sonatype</id>
    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2</url>
  </repository>
  </distributionManagement>

<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptor>dep.xml</descriptor>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.1</version>
      <executions>  
        <execution>
          <id>attach-javadocs</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>jar</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.1</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>attach-sources</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>jar</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 5):

In order to upload jars into the maven repository, you need to sign them with a public key that must be made available at a given key server. See here the [detailed instructions](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/Sonatype+OSS+Maven+Repository+Usage+Guide#SonatypeOSSMavenRepositoryUsageGuide-Signanddeployexistingartifacts), and this [blog post](http://kirang89.github.io/blog/2013/01/20/uploading-your-jar-to-maven-central/) is also helpful.

The most important steps is to create a key and upload it to the key server (detailed in the links above).

Then edit settings.xml to make the PGP key available to Maven:

```
<profiles>
      <profile>
          <id>gpg</id>
          <properties>
              <gpg.passphrase>your passphrase</gpg.passphrase>
              <gpg.keyname>your pgp key</gpg.keyname>
          </properties>
      </profile>
  </profiles>
```

Then  add this in the pom.xml in order to sign the jars:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>sign-artifacts</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>sign</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

this is an example of a [working pom.xml](https://github.com/jhades/jhades/blob/master/pom.xml).

Comment: Ok thanks, with this information I've managed to create the proper pom I think, although there was something weird - I was getting a "duplicated repository tag" on your example of working pom.xml. Anyway, now, I'm getting a 401-unauthorized error when trying to deploy. I've been reading [this FAQ about the 401 problem](http://blog.sonatype.com/2010/11/what-to-do-when-nexus-returns-401/), but  everything mentioned in there seems to be fine for me. Any other suggestions?